# Is it idiomatic to begin a sentence with "In address to"?

Tags: idioms, adverbs, writing-style, tech-writing

I would like to start a sentence with *In address to*.

Example 1

> *In address to* this problem, several examples have been presented.

Example 2

> *In address to* the trade-off between work and rest, as we work more we have a more stressful life.

- Is this sentence grammatically correct?
- Is it idiomatic to start a sentence with such a phrase?
- Is there a better form of expressing the same meaning?

**Update:**

Here, I mean the examples are provided to imply problems. I do not mean that the examples are provided because of the problem.

I feel "with regard to" does not give the same sense. However, I am not sure about it.

Comment: I think you want http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+regard+to

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Thanks very much. Would you please respond to the other questions as well?

Comment: @Stephen Could you use "In address to” in a sentence, so we can get a better understanding what to imply?

Comment: I think I'd expect to see: "To address this problem, [sentence]." Or something more realistic to the idea of solving a problem: "To begin addressing this problem, [sentence]."

Comment: No, *in address to* is not idiomatic. (US English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

> *To address* this problem, several examples have been presented.

Or you could say:

> *While addressing* this problem, several examples have been presented.